# Error: table data has 1 columns but 3 values were supplied Unable to execute statement

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, qml

I'm testing this simple database program using a QML project:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    title: qsTr("SQL Example")
    property var db
    property int ident: 0

    TextField {
        id: field
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter Your Name")
        hoverEnabled: true
    }

    Button {
        text: "Next"
        anchors.top: field.bottom
        onClicked: storeData(field.displayText)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: initDatabase()

    function initDatabase() {
        db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("data", "1.0", "Save names", 1000000)
        db.transaction( function(tx)
        { tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (id INTEGER, name TEXT, mode TEXT)') })
    }

    function storeData(username) {
        db.transaction( function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO data VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [ident, username, ""])
            ident++ })
    }
}
```

When I hit the `Next` button, after entering a name, I get this error message:

*qrc:/main.qml:36: Error: table data has 1 columns but 3 values were supplied Unable to execute statement*

Seemingly everything is right but I don't know why I get this error!

Comment: Is there a case that the table already exists and has only 1 column? Try to execute first: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data` and then create the table.

Comment: @forpas How to execute `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data`, using another function, or inside `initDatabase()`? I'm very new in that code.

Comment: I don't know anything about qml. I can't tell how to execute this statement. It must be executed **once** before the create statement. Then delete it from the code.

Comment: You were right about the table. I renamed `data` to `myData` in the code and the error vanished. I hope there's a way to solve the issue without having to rename the table each time facing such an error.

Comment: You will face this problem every time you make changes like adding or removing or renaming columns. Check the documentation of sqlite and qml on how to handle such cases.

Comment: Huge work to find the exact point where a method is written to get rid of this issue in Docs, because they're very vast.
I thought the `IF NOT EXISTS` parts prevented such an issue.

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` prevents the deletion of the table if it exists. This is the opposite of what you need. You need to delete the table **once** to apply the changes.

Comment: Thank you. How to define the `id` so that it increases for every new row even after relaunching the project, please?

Comment: As AUTOINCREMENT. See these links: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm, http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have.

```
INSERT INTO data VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

The query that must be used as a better practice

```
INSERT INTO data (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

**Thing to note**

Check if the table is already present in the database. That may be the reason why the create table statement is not executing with three column definition. If so remove the table and execute the code it will work.